# EXCEL 2016 VLOOKUp or conditional statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-statements

The aim is to compare a halogen light bulb with a LED bulb to find out which technology is cheapest in the long run.

I want to check when a Halogen bulb burns out during the year. The "lifetime" is lets say 1500 hrs and I need to get new one three times a year.

I have 12 row incremental values (for the number of hrs the light bulb is on) and I want to check if 1500 occurs. The 1500 will never occur as a number. What would be a good way to solve this? VLOOKUP is seaching for an exect number as I have understood it correctly or is it possible to manipulate the function?

There also possiblity to solve it with MOD and at the same time calculate the rest and add it back to the next row. What is best in this case. I am not expecting you to solve this. I am but I need an advice on what is applicable and best solution.

Following parameters are given:
Fixed price for the bulb
Effect, in Watts
Lifespan on the bulb
Price/kWh
How many hrs the bulb will be on during the 24hrs
The number of bulbs, turned on at the same time.
The last four parameters can be changes and they are linked to a graph.

Comment: You haven't explained your problem clearly.  What *exactly* will be the contents of the cell that contains 1500?  You say it will never occur as a number, but what will it occur as? i.e, what precisely is the text you want to check for?

Comment: Are you looking for a cumulative value most close to 1500 in that case? Are the 12 rows fixed always? Are you looking at a prediction based on current 'burnt hours' data?

Comment: The 4th argument in vlookup is 0 for an exact match, but you can put 1 for the “nearest” match , two points “nearest is what vlookup considers and the help file has examples.

Comment: pat2015: Sorry for the delay I needed to get some groceries. the twelve values will change depending on if I change the life time of the light bulb, so the twelve values will change.

Comment: I will try Solar Mike's suggestion for starters.

Answer (score 1):

**@Stacy**,, According to your Query I would like to suggest a useful solution. Here it is finding the Name of the product has highest Life Span.

**Note** for this solution since I found **Index & Match** is technically better and faster so that **NOT USED VLOOKUP**.

[image]

**Formula 1:** =INT((D276-B276)*24) ,calculating Life Span is in **F276** (Drag it down).

**Formaula 2:** calculating the Highest Life Span is in **G276** (don't Drag it since finding the Highest).

=INDEX(A276:A278,MATCH(MAX(F276:F278),F276:F278,FALSE),)&" Life "&MAX(F276:F278)

**NB:** Data range is **A275 to G278** (including Headings).

Change data range as your need.

Hope this help you. Post your opinion also.

Comment: @Stacy,, Excel don't have any Formula to write Numbers in Words, if you have 'Add In' which converts Numbers into Words can be used. VBA code can do this also.